# What exactly is a non-synthetic event (event managed outside react lib)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I know that a synthetic event is for example, **onClick={handlerFunction}**

The question is to **understand React batching**.

Answer (score 2):

An [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) is an API for describing "things that happen" (like clicks).

A native event is one the browser creates.

A [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) is a compatibility API that React generates around native events to normalise differences between browsers.